# How to correctly iterate elements?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, collections

I'm iterating my `Model.Payments` collection (which is an `public IEnumerable<Payments> Payments { get; set; }`):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="payments">
        @foreach (var payment in Model.Payments)
        {
            Html.RenderPartial("_Payment", payment);
        }
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Aggiorna" />
}
```

And this is my `_Payment` partial:

```
@model MyProject.Models.Payments

<div class="payment-row">
    <span>ActivityID:</span> @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ActivityID)
    <span>PaymentType:</span> @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PaymentType)
    <span>Amount:</span> @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Amount)
</div>
```

But it doesn't create a proper HTML. Name/ID are the same, so once I postback, I can't retrieve data.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: I would look into using an Html.EditorForModel() instead of a partial view.  Not sure if that will solve the issue though

Comment: I Need a partial! Lots of content in it...

Comment: You can use a partial for the template

Comment: Can you Place an example? I know there's HtmlBeginCollection for these kind of things, but It seems I can't use it. No library founds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct approach is to use the `EditorFor()` method, which will correctly prefix your inputs with the collection indexer

Rename you partial view to `Payments.cshtml` (to match the name of the class), and move it to the `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` (or `/Views/YourControllerName/EditorTempatesFolder`)

Then you view becomes

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="payments">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Payments)
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Aggiorna" />
}
```

The `EditorFor()` method generates the correct html for each item in the collection, and will generate inputs such as `<input name="Payments[0].ActivityID" ... />` rather than `<input name="ActivityID" ... />` which you are currently generating.

As a side note, you should consider using `@Html.LabelFor()` to generate a `<label>` associated with your form controls, rather than using a `<span>`.

Comment: The name of the `EditorTemplate` must match the name of the class, so you would need to name the partial `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/PaymentViewModel.cshtml` (and in the view it will now be `@model yourAssembly.PaymentViewModel`

Comment: I see :) But what if I want to call it `_Payments.cshtml` instead of `PaymentViewModel.cshtml`?

Comment: Then it will not work unless you were to then make the model in `_Payments.cshtml` `@model List<PaymentViewModel>` and use a `for` loop in the template, and then use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Payments, "_Payments")` - a bit crazy to do that :)

Comment: Why so the convention of `UiHint` and `_Name` inside EditorTemplate folder? I see most of them called in that way!

Comment: The convention is that templates are named the same as the class (internally, that is the first thing the `EditorFor()` (and `DisplayFor()`) method looks for). Both those methods contain overloads that accept either a single object or collection of objects so its quite flexible (and you can also have multiple templates for a class by locating then in the `EditorTemplates` of the controllers view folder). Specifying the view name in `EditorFor()` or using the `[UIHint]` attribute just provides alternative methods, but it means that the template must then match the model

Comment: So because `Payments` is `List<PaymentViewModel>` then `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Payments, "_Payments")` passes `List<PaymentViewModel>` to the template (as opposed to `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Payments)` which (if its `IEnumerable<PaymentViewModel>`) generates the html for each item in the collection based on the template

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174779/discussion-between-markzzz-and-stephen-muecke).